DuckDB - Filename as a parameter in COPY TO statement
Python & DuckDB 1.0
I'm trying to copy a table to a parquet file with the filename passed as a parameter in a prepared statement.
Using a fixed filename works:
def table2parquet(con):
    con.execute(
        f"""
        COPY
            (SELECT ...)
        TO
            'table.parquet' (FORMAT PARQUET)
        """
    )

But, passing the filename as a prepared statement parameter results in a syntax error:
def table2parquet(con, filename):
    con.execute(
        f"""
        COPY
            (SELECT ...)
        TO
            ? (FORMAT PARQUET)
        """,
        [filename]
    )

ParserException: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "?"


Is there a way to do this?
Many thanks

I removed the general, ISO/ANSI  tag since this is a very product specific question.

For Python API you don't have to use PREPARE or EXECUTE SQL statements as
DuckDB co-founder Mark Mytherin commented on the github1.
You can still use parameterized query, I'd split querying and writing into two steps like in this example:
def write_book_reviews(year):
  query = conn.sql(
    """
      SELECT *
      FROM book_reviews
      WHERE review_year=$year
    """,
    params={"year": year}
  )
  query.write_parquet(f"{year}_book_reviews.parquet")


That is very helpful. Thank you.

you can just use parameterized string:
def table2parquet(con, filename):
    con.execute(
        f"""
        COPY
            (SELECT ...)
        TO
            '{filename}' (FORMAT PARQUET)
        """
    )


True. But my my function is a bit more complicated than my simplistic example. I want to pass 2 parameters into the (SELECT ...) clause and a parameter as the filename. I want to "prepare" the statement once with parameter placeholders, and then execute it with multiple parameter combinations. Thanks for your response.

By the way... Passing ? placeholders into the SELECT clause works. It appears only the COPY ... TO ? placeholder is problematic.

This could cause problems if the file name includes characters like single quotes.
